# Automatic syntax highlighting doesn't work for Lua

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

According to this meta question, tag-based syntax highlighting should be working but In [this Lua question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42311/lua-code-review-for-performance-improvements) that was not the case. I suggested an edit to fix the highlighting in the question itself but you can still see the bad highlighting in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42333/8822) (the comments are the wrong color).

Answer (score 4):

I've set the code language hint for the Lua tag to use... Lua highlighting.

All appears as should be now.